# How to convert string YYYYMM to datetime in sql?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a string '2016-03-05' which I want convert to a `datetime`.

Here is my code:

```
Declare @period as nvarchar(10)
Set @period = '2016-03-05'
Select Convert(Datetime, @period, 112).
```

Running that I receive the error

> Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Comment: The string '201605' is not a full datetime - SQL Servers date datatypes don't support year-month only, there is always a day too.

Comment: **Your question is not clear.** In title you mention format `YYYYMM`, in question body you show format `YYYY-MM-DD`.  What format did you actually mean? What is the expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conversion format `112` you've used assumes input `'20160305'` (without dashes as date parts separator).

So either do

```
select convert(Datetime, '20160305', 112)
```

or (if your input really contains dashes then just remove them like:

```
select convert(Datetime, replace('2016-03-05', '-', ''), 112)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the style you're passing to the `CONVERT` function does not support that format. You can do two things...

1- Drop the dashes

```
Declare @period as nvarchar(10)
Set @period = '20160305' --  I've dropped the dashes here
Select Convert(Datetime, @period, 112)
```

2- Change the style to something that supports this format

```
Declare @period as nvarchar(10)
Set @period = '2016-03-05'
Select Convert(Datetime, @period, 21) -- I've changed the style here
```

For a complete reference, read the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LEFT(201605,4) + '-' + RIGHT(201605,2)
{OR} 
SELECT RIGHT(201605,2) + '-' + LEFT(201605,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work I guess according to your need

```
Declare @period as nvarchar(10)
Set @period = '2016-03-05'
select CAST(@period as datetime)
```